# representing data for usage with libsvm (sparse or not)

Tags: machine-learning, format, svm, sparse-matrix, libsvm

I'd like to do some data mining on functions stacktraces, for this I am using libsvm
and representing the data in a sparse format for speed of processing, each stacktrace is an instance and the variables are functions, i.e:

```
class1 F1,F2,F1,F456,F3  
class2 F4,F4,F4,F56,F3000  
...
```

somewhere I have an ever growing registry of seen unique functions, this is where the funcions indexes come from. Ideally, I'd like to represent the aforementioned instances using a sparse format and partitioned in 5 variables like this:

```
1 1:1 2:1 1:1 456:1 3:1  
2 4:1 4:1 4:1 56:1 3000:1
```

this is not possible in libsvm's format, so I am adding the length of the total functions registry to each group to avoid index clashes, if we suppose there are 3000 functions in total:

```
1 1:1 3002:1 6001:1 9456:1 12003:1,  this is how the first instance looks now
```

this works if the amount of functions doesn't change, but that is not the case, as there are new functions added every time, would have to redo whole thing.

I am using a sparse format, but suggestions are welcome on other formats too, I am able to use the data with Weka in a dense format using the function names as variables and it works, just muuch slower than with libsvm

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have few options:

a) redo the whole thing each time (I think generating inputs for libsvm is faster than libsvm itself :))

b) use even numbers for the first thing and odd numbers for the other thing. So your example would look like:

```
1 2:1 3:1 1:1 911:1 5:1
```

This avoids collisions and you don't have to redo the whole thing :)

Comment: thanks @usamec, a) is what I am doing presently, not sure I get b) though? I think a more general question is how do I represent in libsvm sparse format repeating features, i.e. A B A A C, for example. In the previous example I used 5 diff atributes, not sure how odd/even indexes would help? I'm thinking to otherwise resort to the normal dense format and make it 1:2 2:3 3:2 4:2 5:3000 ...